# Getting value from list as a group based on index

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I need to print out a Key which could have multiple values. But I need to print this based on Index. For e.g. if I pass index 0, it should check for A and then print out it's values. Like a 1 to n thing.

Even my below example is printing out the first, as I'm using the .FIRST(). How do I print 1 to N. 1 key with multiple values.

```
    recordList = new List<MyData>();
      MyData add = new MyData { Data1 = "A", Data2 = "A is for Apple" };
        recordList.Add(add);
        MyData add1 = new MyData { Data1 = "A", Data2 = "B is for Ball" };
        recordList.Add(add1);
        MyData add2 = new MyData { Data1 = "A", Data2 = "C is for Cat" };
        recordList.Add(add2);
        MyData add3 = new MyData { Data1 = "A", Data2 = "D is for Doll" };
        recordList.Add(add3);

    MyData add4 = new MyData { Data1 = "B", Data2 = "A is for Apple" };
        recordList.Add(add4);
        MyData add5 = new MyData { Data1 = "B", Data2 = "B is for Ball" };
        recordList.Add(add5);
        MyData add6 = new MyData { Data1 = "B", Data2 = "C is for Cat" };
        recordList.Add(add6);
        MyData add7 = new MyData { Data1 = "B", Data2 = "D is for Doll" };
        recordList.Add(add7);



var data = recordList.AsParallel().ToLookup(x => x.Data1, (x) =>
         {
             return (from m in recordList where m.Data1 == x.Data1 select new MyData { Data2 = m.Data2, Data1 = m.Data1 }).First();

         });

  var output = data["A"];
            foreach(var print in output)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(print.Data1 + "   "+ print.Data2);
            }
```

The result I want to Acheive is :

```
A    A is for Apple
     B is for Ball
     C is for Cat
     D is for Doll
```

Because instead of printing this I want to pass this to another method. SO I should I have one key with it's corresponding values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group items by `Data1` property:

```
var groups = recordList.GroupBy(d => d.Data1);
```

Then you will have items grouped by their `Data1` value.

```
foreach(var data1Group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data1Group.Key); // group key A or B

    foreach(var data in data1Group)
        Console.WriteLine(data.Data2);
}
```

Or use [lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
var lookup = recordList.ToLookup(d => d.Data1, d => d.Data2);

// getting items for A
foreach(var data2 in lookup["A"])
   Console.WriteLine(data2);
```

You can skip projecting lookup items

```
var lookup = recordList.ToLookup(d => d.Data1);
```

In this case lookup will be like a groups, but with indexed access by key.

---

Whats wrong in your code? Lets see what it does

```
 var data = recordList.ToLookup(x => x.Data1, (x) =>
 {
     return (from m in recordList 
             where m.Data1 == x.Data1 
             select new MyData { Data2 = m.Data2, Data1 = m.Data1 }).First();
 });
```

It groups items in `recordList` by `Data1` property value, and for each item in group it puts into lookup following value:

```
  (from m in recordList 
   where m.Data1 == x.Data1 
   select new MyData { Data2 = m.Data2, Data1 = m.Data1 }).First()
```

Result of this query will be same for all items in group - it goes to `recordList` finds first item with same `Data1` as current item (but not same item!) and creates its copy. Thus you end up with lookup filled with copies of first items in each group.

Comment: Can I pass an index to the lookup. If for e.g. I need to get it by index instead of Passing "A"

Comment: @user726720 `lookup.ElementAt(1)`? If you want to get items with `B`. But that has no sense to me. Power of lookup is getting items by their grouping value

Comment: I have a binarysearch method which will return me the closest index to what I'm looking for. THen I want to take this index value and pull up the MYDATA.Data1 and MYData.Data2 from it, but with your lookup i think I can only pull the elements. why I can't pull up the key. if in the Console.writeline(data2.Data1, data2.Data2)

Comment: @user726720 see *You can skip projecting lookup items* part

Comment: thanks mate it works, I'm a bit weak in the LINQ part of C#, do you any easy literature that can help me understand LINQ. Thank you for sharing

Comment: Do you have any easy to understand guide for linq. Please share

Comment: @user726720 there is two nice guides - one is pluralsight.com video about LINQ (there is demo access available). Another one is Jon Skeet *Re-implementing LINQ* series of articles - with them you will understand internals of LINQ